# delayed_jobs save completed jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

Is there a parameter I can pass to delayed_job that will prevent it from deleting completed jobs from the delayed_jobs table?

kind of like the `destroy_failed_jobs` but for completed jobs

any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't appear so. From the README: https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job

> By default, it will delete failed jobs (and it always deletes
>   successful jobs). If you want to keep failed jobs, set
>   Delayed::Job.destroy_failed_jobs = false. The failed jobs will be
>   marked with non-null failed_at.

You would probably need to hook into its destroy method such that it copies the job to another, separate table that keeps the list of completed jobs for you, or to simply log which jobs have been done to a file, if a log is all you need.

What you don't want is to leave the jobs in the `delayed_jobs` table, for a couple of reasons. First, because `delayed_jobs` uses that table as it's TODO list - you want it to only be things that still need to be done. Second, if you hacked it to keep all jobs in the same table, then the `delayed_jobs` table only grows, which would slow down the processing of `delayed_jobs` over time, as the query to find jobs that have **not yet** been completed would have to **filter out those that have**.

Answer (score 10):

Expanding on @jefflunt's answer.

I added a migration to create a table to contain the completed jobs

```
class CreateCompletedJobs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :completed_jobs do |t|
      t.integer  "priority", :default => 0
      t.integer  "attempts", :default => 0
      t.text     "handler", :limit => 2147483647
      t.datetime "run_at"
      t.datetime "completed_at"
      t.string   "queue"
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Then a module

```
class CompletedJob < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Finally added the hook to the job I want to store

```
  def success job
    save_completed_job job
  end

  private

  def save_completed_job job
    CompletedJob.create({
      priority: job.priority,
      attempts: job.attempts,
      handler: job.handler,
      run_at: job.run_at,
      completed_at: DateTime.now,
      queue: job.queue
    })
  end
```

Since I have more then one job I placed the success method hook in a module and included it in all the jobs I would like to store. (Note: some  aren't worth storing)

Comment: What can be done to save it for all jobs, more details I have added [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41742169/hook-before-all-delyed-job-success-callback-to-save-successfully-completed-jobs).

Comment: Just a note that this won't work if you're using ActiveJob because then DelayedJob callbacks are not available. You must instead use ActiveJob callbacks. (Unfortunately, ActiveJob callbacks only have access to ActiveJob job object)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [acts_as_paranoid](https://github.com/technoweenie/acts_as_paranoid).

It basically works like this:

- *#destroy* is overwritten so that records are not deleted from the database but instead a deleted_at timestamp is set
- a default scope is installed so that *.find* (and all its variations) don't return items from the database where the deleted_at timestamp is set

Here is an introduction: http://technicalpickles.com/posts/embracing-your-paranoia-with-acts_as_paranoid/

Beware: acts_as_paranoid is very old and there are maybe better solutions, so check out https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Soft_Delete